# Is there a way to test termination in Haskell using existing libraries?

Tags: haskell, testing, termination

There are some libraries in Haskell for testing properties or for unit tests, etc. But I have yet to find one that allows for testing termination/nontermination of a function.

Of course you can't simply test if an expression terminates because of the Halting problem. But I could have a guess on the upper bound of how long the function takes to evaluate and if the function doesn't end in that time, the test would fail as the function was (likely) not going to terminate.

Is there a library that allows for testing termination like this?

Comment: This functionality (terminate evaluation after a time) is provided in the base libraries by [System.Timeout](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/System-Timeout.html).

Comment: Oh, that's cool. Didn't know about that.

I wonder if it works properly for non IO computations if I use `return`, but it probably should.

Comment: @TheRedFox I expect it'd do what you want if you [fully force](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.1.2/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html) the computation before returning its result (ie `timeout 1000 (return $!! map +1 [1..1000000])`)

Comment: Don't use `return $!!`. It's not quite guaranteed to do what you want in the face of optimizations, I don't think. Use `evaluate . force`.